# Устойчивость initializer list к изменениям кода

Tags: c++, инициализация

Есть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Range {
    //bool enabled = false;
    //int index = 0;
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Range r = { 2, 3 };
    std::cout << r.begin << " " << r.end;
}
```

Если я изменю состав структуры `Range`, раскомментировав одну из закомментированных строчек, то программа скомпилируется, но работать будет неправильно. Если добавить в начало `Range` поле типа `bool`, то компилятор хотя бы будет выдавать предупреждение. А если добавить в начало `Range` поле типа `int`, то даже предупреждений не будет.

Есть ли какой-то способ сделать так, чтобы при изменении состава структуры все initializer lists, инициализирующие её, стали невалидными или хотя бы выдавали предупреждение при компиляции? Ну или может быть есть какой-то другой надёжный способ найти все initializer lists в коде инициализирующие данную структуру?

В общем, нужен какой-то надёжный способ обойти все места инициализации и убедиться, что структура правильно инициализируется после изменений.

Comment: Кросс-пост: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77526761/2752075

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - в английском варианте там ответ совсем непонятен...

Comment: @AlexGlebe Почему, вроде наоборот понятно.

Comment: при переводе, говорит что нужно сделать конструктор. Но если в конструктор добавить значения по-умолчанию, то приходим в ту-же проблему. надо подумать @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @AlexGlebe Так не надо добавлять аргумент по умолчанию, если цель - отловить все использования структуры в коде и дописать туда недостающие инициализаторы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для надёжности можно передать с именованными полями структуру так :

```cpp
Range r = { . begin = 2 , . end = 3 } ;
```

В плюсах добавили в C++20 , в Си было в С99.

---

В английском варианте вопроса
[How to make initializer lists robust to code changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77526761/2752075) предлагают сделать конструктор с новым количеством аргументов. Это даст вам возможность переписать везде код, добавляя новый аргумент. *Выставлять аргументам значения по умолчанию не надо, а то не поможет.*

```cpp
struct Range {
    //bool enabled = false;
    int index = 0;
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
  // новый конструктор, требующий три аргумента
  Range ( int i , int b , int e ) :
    index{i},begin{b},end{e}{}  
  // старый конструктор, требующий два аргумента
  Range ( int b , int e ) :
    begin{b},end{e}{}  
};

int main(){
  // старый код
  Range r = { 2, 3 };
  // новый код
  Range nr = { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

До тех пор, пока при инициализации отсутствует контроль по именам членов класса, могут появляться неоднозначности, особенно, когда типы членов совпадают или для них допустимы неявные преобразования. Варианты с именами рассмотрены в соседнем ответе: версия C++20 и конструктор (или конструкторы).

Но есть и другой подход. Если на текущий момент код валидный, и новые члены структуры добавляются только в конец, то проблем с агрегатной инициализацией не возникнет.

```
struct Range {
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
    bool enabled = false;
    int index = 0;
};

Range r = { 2, 3 };
```

Хвостовые элементы, не инициализированные явно, будет инициализированы значениями по умолчанию.